# Anyway to test Postgres DB connection via command line without external tools?

Tags: bash, postgresql

Is there a way to test a connection to a Postgres DB via command line (bash) without using external tools, such as `psql` or `pg_isready`? Trying to write a bash script.

Comment: What exactly do you consider external? Any binary that is invoked from bash? Or only binaries that are not part of a standard Linux distribution. If e.g. `telnet localhost 5432` would be a minimal test to see if something is listening on the default Postgres port. But to be 100% sure, you need _some_ program that actually establishes a connection.

Comment: The latter - I'd consider external to mean anything not part of the standard Linux distribution.

Comment: ncat -z 0.0.0.0 5432 (Or whatever port your psql instance is listening to)